# Get last element of a line

Tags: java, string

```
0 0 2 2 6 5 0.61 1
14 2 15 3 6 1 0.123 -1
```

I am trying to get

```
0 0 2 2 6 5 0.61
14 2 15 3 6 1 0.123
```

For that I did

```
String predictLine = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
```

For 1 st line it is ok,but for last line it is showing

```
14 2 15 3 6 1 0.123 -
```

Am I doing anything wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" "))`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to remove the last tokens, it should be:

```
line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

(note that substring excludes the 'to' index)

If on the other hand you are interested in the last token itself:

```
line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd split the string and treat it as an array:

```
String[] splitted = line.split(" ");
String lastItem = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
```

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder yup, stupid typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the line and get the last element by:

```
String line = "0 0 2 2 6 5 0.61 1";
String[] split = line.split(" ");
String lastElement = split[split.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get string from beginning to last index of `" "` You can see in Docs

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.
```

In your case `beginIndex` would be `0` and `endIndex` would be lastIndexOf `" "`

So you can just do it like this -

`line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf(" "))`

Docs `-->`  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)